# How can two different Node.js servers communicate to one mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two servers (Public server and Admin Server) and I would like to access from both one mongoose schema. The main server is the Public one where everything happens, but sometimes, from Admin server I would like to access that schema. I could write the schema on both the servers, but that would mean bad code. If that is the only solution, I will do it. But, is there any other way of doing this? For MongoDB I have a third server, that is only for database. Could I write something there so that when I connect with mongoose to the MongoDB server to receive the model from there?

Let's say I have this code (somewhere, I don't know where yet).

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

const Post = new mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

What I am trying to do in a server file is for example to call `Post.save()` or whatever function I am trying to get, without having the schema on both servers.

Comment: Create a file that can be accessed from both servers (if they share same hardware) and read those files to get the schema.The exports might work if you share same hardware ,you can always require them by giving the absolute path.

Comment: @Shubh I have droplets from DigitalOcean, so I guess they don't share the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I used Mongoose-Gen npm and created an API in order to get the schema from on server to another.